# How to use a relative program path in a PhpStorm file watcher

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, file-watcher

In PhpStorm (as well as other JetBrains IDEs, I'm sure), I'm setting up a File Watcher. In the Watcher Settings section, it asks me to specify the path to the program to be executed.

I want to use the executable file within the `node_modules/.bin` directory of my project. I don't want it installed globally because I may have other projects that use the same program, but may require a different version.

I could simply specify the absolute path to my project's `node_modules/.bin` directory, but then if I move the project, the file watcher will break.

In the **Arguments** and **Output paths to refresh** fields just below the **Program** field, it allows you to insert a macro, like `$Projectpath$`. This is exactly what I need, but it doesn't look like the **Program** field allows that.

Is there a way to specify a relative path for the **Program** field?

Here is a screenshot of the File Watcher setup window:

[image: PhpStorm File Watcher setup window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could simply specify the absolute path to my project's `node_modules/.bin` directory, but then if I move the project, the file watcher will break.

That's not true -- at very least it does not break anything here -- got 3 projects that use local stuff.

> Is there a way to specify a relative path for the Program field?

Sure. **Use full path** to the program :)

Internally (in config file) it will be stored using `$PROJECT_DIR$` (AFAIK) special macro/variable but in actual field (in that dialog window) you will always see full path. Such conversion is done automatically.

You can read a bit more here (in comments): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24376

---

If you are using the same project on different computers ... where path to the same program will be different but outside of the project (e.g. stored inside user-specific folder and user logins/names are different on such computers) ... you could use Path Variables functionality (`Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Path Variables`) and specify the same variable on all of such computers that would point to correct path on that computer. IDE will automatically use that path variable to store the path.

So .. on one computer `MY_TOOL_PATH` will be pointing to `/Users/Joe/MyTool` and on another it could be `/Users/Sam/AnotherTool`.

Comment: You're right...I didn't realize it would convert the full path that I specify to a relative path when stored. This doesn't seem obvious at all. I'll leave a comment on the YouTrack issue. Thanks!